# Google Calendar API insert method not working on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use Google Calendar API in my Ruby project and I meet a problem when I try to use the insert in the API. When I try the sample code on the https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples,
I end up getting an error.

```
insertEvent.rb:2:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Google (NameError)
```

And if I paste this sample code after the quickstart.rb on this page
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby, I will get this error:

```
quickstart.rb:84:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `client' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Google did not get me the definition of client variable here so I do not what to insert here. I am a new learner of Ruby and thank you so much for helping.

Here is the code that I am stuck in

```
result = client.insert_event('primary', event)
puts "Event created: #{result.html_link}"
```

Comment: Sounds like the gem isn't loaded properly, or you're calling it wrong. Have you declared that in your `Gemfile`? Did you `bundle install`? Have you restarted your Rails process(es) after doing that?

Comment: @tadman I tried this in a ruby folder and I can run the quickstart.rb without exception. But the insert method will give me an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, client isn't defined.  Try this example code instead

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/samples/cli/lib/samples/calendar.rb

and

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby

Important parts here:

```
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
require 'fileutils'

OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'.freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Ruby Quickstart'.freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'credentials.json'.freeze
TOKEN_PATH = 'token.yaml'.freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_READONLY

def authorize
  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(CREDENTIALS_PATH)
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: TOKEN_PATH)
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(client_id, SCOPE, token_store)

  # figure out your user_id
  user_id = 'default'
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(base_url: OOB_URI)
    puts 'Open the following URL in the browser and enter the ' \
      "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
      user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
    )
  end
  credentials
end

calendar = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
calendar.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
calendar.authorization = authorize

event = {
  summary: 'Events',
  attendees: [
    {email: 'lpage@example.com'},
    {email: 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
  start: {
    date_time: '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  end: {
    date_time: '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  }
}

event = calendar.insert_event('primary', event, send_notifications: true)
```

and don't forget to run this first:

```
gem install google-api-client
```

and also to create these files with the correct authentication information

1. `credentials.json`
2. `token.yaml`

and to figure out your `user_id`.